# MySQL Prevent sum twice

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have the following query in my PHP script:

```
SELECT SUM(score) + 1200 AS rating
FROM users_ratings
WHERE user_fk = ?
```

The problem is that if the user has no rows in the table, the rating is returned as `NULL`. So I added an if case:

```
SELECT IF(SUM(score) IS NULL, 0, SUM(score)) + 1200 AS rating
FROM users_ratings
WHERE user_fk = ?
```

But now I'm wondering how to do the query, without repeating the `SUM(score)`. I'm guessing if I have lot of rows, the sum would repeat twice, which would affect the performance of the application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simpler method:

```
SELECT ( COALESCE(SUM(score), 0) + 1200 ) AS rating
FROM users_ratings
WHERE user_fk = ?;
```

`COALESCE()` is an ANSI standard function that returns the first non-`NULL` value from a list of expressions.

However, the additional overhead of calculating `SUM(score)` twice -- even if it happens -- should be very minimal compared to the rest of the query (finding the data, reading it in, summarizing it to one row).